# Need to set background to non using Imagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to translate the following ImageMagick command

```
-background none
```

to php. I tried the document and the example in the document

[view document](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagebackgroundcolor.php)

```
setImageBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'))
```

but the background still remains white. Any experts can throw some light here?

Comment: What's your output (file) format?

Comment: -background none is just a setting and needs an operator to apply it. If you have a constant background color such as white or black and want to change it to transparent, then you need the command line command of -transparent white or -transparent black, etc. In Imagick, that would be http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.transparentpaintimage.php

Comment: You need to be using a format that supports transparency - so avoid JPEG and consider PNG/GIF/TIFF.